# Using with open, why does 'rb' for reading json work but 'wb' for writing to a json does not?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I noticed that when using `with open` to read a json, using either `r` or `rb` parameters returns identical results.

```
with open('something.json', 'rb') as f # 'r' returns the same thing
    t1 = json.load(f)
```

However, when I write to a json with `wb`, I get an error:

```
with open('something.json', 'wb') as f:
  json.dump(some_dict, f)
```

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

But `w` works fine. Why is this the case?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](//docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)? *"The json module always produces str objects, not bytes objects. Therefore, `fp.write()` must support str input."*

Answer (score 2):

When opening the file in read-only binary mode `rb`, `f.read()` function returns bytes instead of string (for text mode), both of which are acceptable for [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) function argument

When openning the file in write-only binary mode `wb`, `f.write()` function only supports byte-like objects as argument instead of `str`. so when [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) calls it and trying to pass the string value to `f.write`, it will raise the exception you saw above

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are not writing in binary form over the JSON, try using `json.dumps(some_dict)` to transform your dictionary into a json file and then use `some_dict.encode('utf-8')` to write to it as binary.
Something like this:

```
json_data = json.dumps(data)
with open('something.json', 'wb') as f:
f.write(json_data.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.6, the `json` module tries to auto-detect the encoding of a binary file when reading JSON. UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32 are supported.

However, this doesn't work when writing. There's no way to auto-detect what encoding you wanted to use when writing. `json` could make an assumption, like `open` does when you open a file in text mode without specifying an encoding, but the tradeoffs are different.

If `json` were to assume UTF-8 encoding (or any other encoding) when writing to a binary file, then you might end up reading UTF-32 and writing UTF-8 and not noticing the encoding change until some other code that needs UTF-32 breaks. That's less of an issue with `open`, because `open` makes the same assumption when reading or writing, instead of trying to auto-detect encoding when reading.

Since auto-detection is impossible and assuming an encoding would be error-prone, `json` requires you to give it a text file when writing.

Comment: If I use 'w' to write to a json, does it matter if I use 'r' or 'rb' to load it back after?

Answer (score 0):

Since `json.load` and `json.loads` are given data to inspect, they try to guess an encoding for the data when given binary. But it can't do that when dumping data because there isn't anything to inspect. So, there is a lack of symmetry. You can give a binary file to the reader, risking that it will guess encoding incorrectly. But not the writer. It will only work with strings and you are expected to deal with encoding on your own.

Personally, I wouldn't trust the encoding guesser and would always open in "r" mode with an explicit encoding.